# Java String index of

Tags: java

I am looking for a simplified logic to get substring of string if the string matches set of sequences.
To be more precise, I am looking for a way to extract person name entered in address line 2 of an address.

Here is an example string patterns:

Example code written to address the possible sequences:

```
  String addressLine2 = "attn: jane doe";
String addressLine2 = "attn jane doe";
String addressLine2 = "atn: jane doe";
String addressLine2 = "at: jane doe";
String addressLine2 = "at  jane doe";
String addressLine2 = "atn jane doe";

     public static String parseContactNameFromAttnLine(String originalAddressLine2){
            String addressLine2 = originalAddressLine2.toUpperCase();
            int i = addressLine2.indexOf("ATTN ");
            if (i >= 0) {
              i += 5; // contact name starts from 5th position
            } else {
              i = addressLine2.indexOf("ATTN: ");
              if (i >= 0) {
                i += 6;
              } else {
                i = addressLine2.indexOf("ATTN:");
                if (i >= 0) {
                  i += 5;
                } else {
                  i = addressLine2.indexOf("ATN ");
                  if (i >= 0) {
                    i += 4;
                  } else {
                    i = addressLine2.indexOf("AT:");
                    if (i >= 0) {
                      i += 3;
                    } else{
                        i = addressLine2.indexOf("ATN:");
                        if (i >= 0) {
                          i += 3;
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            String contactName = null;
            if (i >= 0) {
              contactName = addressLine2.substring(i).trim();
            }
        
            return contactName;
          }
```

I am sure this logic can be simplified in a concise way. I am open to use the apache utils library as well. I don't find the method I needed it.

Appreciate if any one has thoughts on this. Thanks!

Comment: The first word is always what you look out for?

Comment: Yes, my character sequence always start at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use case for a regular expression.  You can adjust the regular expression based on what line formats you want to accept and what you don't.  Nothing else in the code has to change...just the one line that defines the regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {

    // Expression: some combination of the letterns `a`, `t`, or `n`, followed
    // optionally by a colon, followed by whitespace, ending with the
    // desired value.
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[atn]+:?\\s+(.*)");

    public static String parseContactNameFromAttnLine(String address) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(address);
        if (matcher.matches())
            return matcher.group(1);
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] addresses = {"attn: jane doe",
                "attn jane doe",
                "atn: jane doe",
                "at: jane doe",
                "at  jane doe",
                "atn jane doe"};

        for (String address : addresses)
            System.out.println(parseContactNameFromAttnLine(address));
    }
    
}
```

Result:

```
jane doe
jane doe
jane doe
jane doe
jane doe
jane doe
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Simple and concise solution. Thanks for the suggestion. I made it case insensitive matching use this:Pattern.compile("[ATN]+:?\\s+(.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); Please let me know if there is a way to specify pattern case insensitive within matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the first word is always the identifier. Not the most optimal solution, but something for you to continue.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Following are tests, check the output section below
        String addressLine2 = "attn jane doe";
        String ret = getName(addressLine2);
        System.out.println("ret = " + ret);
        
        addressLine2 = "atn: jane doe";
        ret = getName(addressLine2);
        System.out.println("ret = " + ret);
        
        addressLine2 = "at: jane doe";
        ret = getName(addressLine2);
        System.out.println("ret = " + ret);
        
        addressLine2 = "at  jane doe";
        ret = getName(addressLine2);
        System.out.println("ret = " + ret);
        
        addressLine2 = "atn jane doe";
        ret = getName(addressLine2);
        System.out.println("ret = " + ret); 
    }

    public static String getName(String addressLine2) {
        String[] words = addressLine2.split(" ");
        String[] strings = Arrays.copyOfRange(words, 1, words.length);
        return String.join(" ", strings);
    }
```

Output:

```
ret = jane doe
ret = jane doe
ret = jane doe
ret =  jane doe
ret = jane doe
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am using the regex code to simplify the loops and if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh ok first you will split the name by space as it should have one in given example then concatenate them in a loop till its length with the space after each itereatin then if there is some condition like string "at jane doe" you will get extra space at the start of string which is solved by .trim() method.

```
static String addressLine2 = "at  jane doe";

     public static void main(String []args){
        parseContactNameFromAttnLine(addressLine2);
     }
 

     public static String parseContactNameFromAttnLine(String originalAddressLine2){
        String add = "";
        String arr [] = originalAddressLine2.split(" ");
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            add += arr[i] + " ";
        
        add = add.trim();
        System.out.println(add);
        return add;
    }
```

Comment: Input string does not always contain space as that is optional. I am using the regex pattern to implement my requirement. But thanks again for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Yeah regex is good but after "at" there should be some seperator or symbol to identify its a seperate word